# neo4j find nodes with similar connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

I am trying to figure out the following problem: I have two nodes `:Merchant` and `:Customer`. The two are related with a `:BUY` relationship. 
I am trying to find `:Merchant` nodes that have the same `:Customer` nodes, or even better, that share let's say 90% of the `:Customer`nodes. 
Thank you.

Comment: And how far have you gone?

Comment: What do you mean? Haven't solve it yet

Answer (score 0):

This helped me: 
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/similarity-jaccard/

It's important that all nodes you want to compare are in the same graph and connected.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(cuisine)
WITH {item:id(p), categories: collect(id(cuisine))} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data)
YIELD item1, item2, count1, count2, intersection, similarity
RETURN algo.getNodeById(item1).name AS from, algo.getNodeById(item2).name AS to, intersection, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

should be something like this, (it depends on your db)

```
MATCH (p:Merchant)-[:BUY]->(consumer)
WITH {item:id(p), categories: collect(id(consumer))} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data)
YIELD item1, item2, count1, count2, intersection, similarity
WHERE similarity > 0.9
RETURN algo.getNodeById(item1).name AS from, algo.getNodeById(item2).name AS to, intersection, similarity
ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

By my understanding it uses the jaccard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) to the id of the node.

PS: It is important to install the plugin to use it:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/#_installation